# Google spreadsheet query: How do I stop Range appearing as a result?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good evening,

I'm trying to use some coding skills to help manipulate a spreadsheet in Google Docs and think the logic I've worked out is sound - but the script just returns results as 'Range'.

Essentially the script is a nested loop and (should) take values from six points in a row of data (starting in 11) and plonk them into a long vertical (column 38). Then it should move onto the next row.

I think it works, but the results just come back as 'Range' and can't see how to put the values into range, if that's what this means.

I also realise that it might be more effective to use a single array to gather the data on an individual array, but I'm still trying to get to grips with the syntax.

Here's my code:

```
function Transform() {
  //load spreadsheet data and initialise variables

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var firstrow = 11;//this is a manual figure
  var d = firstrow;
  var valuerplc = sheet.getRange(firstrow, 38);
  var value =1;

  for(var c=firstrow; c<sheet.getLastRow(); c++){
    for (var e=3; e<33; e=e+6){
      var mon = sheet.getRange(c, e);
      valuerplc = sheet.getRange(d, 38);
      valuerplc.setValue(mon);

    }
    d++;

   }
  }
```

Can anyone help, or at least point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: I don't see any return statements in that code at all.  I would have expected a direct call to return undefined.

Comment: I don't think you need them, or at least, I've not had to use them in order to return values in the spreadsheet. It's just that they're not as I would expect.

Comment: ahh, I see.  The method has a side-effect, which is to drop the range of values into the target range.

Answer (score 0):

You've been caught with a common newbie problem, having trouble differentiating between Ranges and Values.

A Range expresses a region of a spreadsheet, with methods that give you access to various characteristics of the object. The contents, or data that you see in a spreadsheet is accessible via the `.getValue()` method (for one cell) or `.getValues()` (for more than one cell).

Change:

```
var mon = sheet.getRange(c, e);
```

To:

```
var mon = sheet.getRange(c, e).getValue();
```

... and you'll have the data that's in that range, as a String, Number or Date, depending on what was there.

The variable names you've selected may lead to confusion, it's worthwhile being careful with that. For example, look at `valuerplc`. The name implies that it's a value, which can be confused with `.getValue()` and `.setValue()`. But the way that it's used is as a Range, as in `valuerplc.setValue(mon)`, so it's clearly NOT a value.

```
function Transform() {
  //load spreadsheet data and initialise variables

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var firstrow = 11;//this is a manual figure
  var d = firstrow;
  var valuerplc = sheet.getRange(firstrow, 38);
  var value =1;

  for(var c=firstrow; c<sheet.getLastRow(); c++){
    for (var e=3; e<33; e=e+6){
      var mon = sheet.getRange(c, e).getValue();
      valuerplc = sheet.getRange(d, 38);
      valuerplc.setValue(mon);
    }
    d++;
  }
}
```